# Hyper-V not able to start? Don't know what to do with the error message

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am using Windows 10 Education (Version 1709) and I just enabled Hyper-V and rebooted, then began by creating a new VM. This is the first time I've tried running a VM on my computer (had used them before at my Uni PC's) and I can't get it to run. It spits out an error.

[image: The error]

The error isn't very specific, and Googling the issue brings me to solutions that I think are not applicable, because the majority of them had a VM that was previously working, but stopped. My VM's have never been able to start up.

Tried creating VM's on other drives, adding more RAM, and using the "quick create" tool. Getting the same error each time I try to start one up no matter what I modify.

Any ideas what I might be missing? I have plenty of drive space and available RAM, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

I didn't want to go modifying registry files if that was unnecessary, as I could potentially make it worse.

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer to see further messages?

Comment: Hi @music2myear, thanks for the suggestion. I've opened it up but I'm not quite sure what to look for. There are thousands of error reports. Almost all Hyper-V ones say "New Virtual Machine' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID FEC953C7-5FE6-4ED8-B49D-805862E1D14A)" and nothing else. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: There will be codes with each of those errors, and you can search those.

Comment: @music2myear Would that be the Event ID? Mine says 15130, I should look that up?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @music2myear following this guide (number 3 on bottom) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd582049(v=ws.10). I typed "net start nvspwmi" and got an error back saying "The service name is invalid"... Where do I go from here?

Comment: That doc is more of a pointer for you than a list of specific steps, because it is about Windows Server 2008, where the service names may be different. You can find the names of the services in the Services list and manually restart them, or you can find the service names and substitute the appropriate names in the prescribed commands.